# mouse coordinates on entire window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mouseevent

my code is supposed to display the coordinates of the mouse as it relates to the enitre window, but the method I used will only give coordinates for each individual component. how do i get coordinates for the entire window and all components?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Clock extends JFrame implements ActionListener, Runnable, MouseMotionListener {
    public static final int w = 500;
    public static final int l = 200;
    public JLabel label;
    String msg= null;
    public int color=0;
      int xpos; 
         int ypos;
         JTextField xf = new JTextField("b");
         JTextField yf = new JTextField("d");
         JTextField butf = new JTextField("f");
     Date date = new Date();

      String DATE_FORMAT = "hh:mm:ss";

      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)  
         {  

          xpos = e.getX();
          ypos = e.getY();
          xf.setText(""+xpos);
          yf.setText(""+ypos);

         }
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)  
         {  
              xpos = me.getX(); 
              ypos = me.getY(); 
         }
    public Clock() {
        super("CS 302 Lab 7");
        addMouseMotionListener(this); 
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new GridLayout( 1,0));
        top.setLayout(new GridLayout( 1,0));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(w, l);

        JLabel x = new JLabel("X");
        x.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        JLabel y = new JLabel("Y");
        y.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        JLabel but = new JLabel("Button");
        but.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        xf.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        yf.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        butf.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        top.add(x);
        top.add(xf);
        top.add(y);
        top.add(yf);
        top.add(but);
        top.add(butf);

        msg = (sdf.format(date));
        label = new JLabel(msg, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 40));

        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, label);

        JButton red = new JButton("Red");
        main.add(red);
        red.addActionListener(this);


        JButton green = new JButton("Green");
        main.add(green);
        green.addActionListener(this);

        JButton blue = new JButton("Blue");
        main.add(blue);
        blue.addActionListener(this);

        JButton orange = new JButton("Orange");
        main.add(orange);
        orange.addActionListener(this);

        red.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        blue.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        green.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        orange.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        SwingUtilities.convertPoint(red, x, y, destination)
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, main );
        add(BorderLayout.NORTH, top );
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  Clock clock = new Clock();
        Runnable rn = new Clock();
        Thread th = new Thread(rn);
        th.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Red")){
            Date date = new Date();
            msg = (sdf.format(date));
            label.setText(msg);
            label.setForeground(Color.RED);
            color=1;
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Blue")){
            Date date = new Date();
            msg = (sdf.format(date));
            label.setText(msg);
            label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            color=2;
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Green")){
            Date date = new Date();
            msg = (sdf.format(date));
            label.setText(msg);
            label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            color=3;
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Orange")){
            Date date = new Date();
            msg = (sdf.format(date));
            label.setText(msg);
            label.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
            color=4;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
             Date date = new Date();
        msg = (sdf.format(date));
        label.setText(msg);
        if (color ==1)
            label.setForeground(Color.RED);
        else if (color ==2)
            label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        else if (color ==3)
            label.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        else if (color ==4)
            label.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SwingUtilities.convertPoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint%28java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29). Try this in your mouseMoved() method:

> Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), e.getPoint(),
>   getContentPane());

Update the destination component as needed, I used getContentPane() to convert to the coordinates of frame's contentPane.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this code snipped return coordinates to the JFrame, there is frustrated get the JFrame, because is extended

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        Point p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(e.getComponent(), e.getPoint(), container);
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(p.x);
        System.out.println(p.y);
        /*public static Point convertPoint(Component source, int x, int y, Component destination)
        Convert the point (x,y) in source coordinate system to destination coordinate system.
        If source is null, (x,y) is assumed to be in destination's root component coordinate
        system. If destination is null, (x,y) will be converted to source's root component
        coordinate system. If both source and destination are null, return (x,y) without any conversion.*/
        xpos = e.getX();
        ypos = e.getY();
        xf.setText("" + xpos);
        yf.setText("" + ypos);
    }
```